# How can I sync the RPM of a DC electric motor to the RPM of a rotating mechanical shaft?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

An example would be the mechanical shaft is rotating at 50 rpm and the electric motor would be at 800rpm and this would scale up.

Comment: Welcome!  I have an answer to what I think your question is but not quite sure.  What is the "this" that would scale up, and what does scaling up mean?

Comment: We have a yanmar diesel powered conveyor, stepped down via a gear reduction box. We would like to have a second electric powered conveyor that runs parallel in sync with it, but remains independent in the event the other one has downtime.

Comment: DC electric motor is too vague. There are many kinds. It doesn't even completely rule out some AC motors when you say "DC motor".

Comment: Gears and a one-way clutch.

Answer (score 1):

You drive the motor with a motor controller that can accept a speed reference signal and stick a tachometer or encoder on the shaft you are tracking and use that as the speed reference.

Alternatively, connect the two together with a clutch if the motor and diesel engine will share the load properly.